# Программа будет ли работать быстрее если

Tags: c#, c++, python, алгоритм, оптимизация

Мне стало интересно,что если на **высокоуровневом** языке допустим `python`  писать программу и заменять `\n` пробел  на `0x0a`  `0x00`.

**Низкоуровневые** языки такие как `с` `с++` `с#` они компилируются они напрямую скажем так работают через цп, программа не будет тормозить

а вот **высокоуровневые** языки они работаю медленнее и вот мне стало интересно будет ли программа работать чуточку быстрее, если некоторые элементы заменять на машинные команды?

Comment: программа будет работать быстрее, если вы используете подходящие структуры данных и алгоритмы. Все остальное требуется только в сильно замороченных случаях

Comment: Внезапно `0x0a` - это то же самое что `\n`, а вовсе не машинная команда. Высокоуровневые языки обычно не позволяют просто так использовать машинные команды. C# - Это язык высокого уровня со сборкой мусора и без использования натив билда он обычно интерпретируется, ну или в лучшем случае транслируется на лету.

Comment: А давно ли C# стал низкоуровневым языком?

Comment: @LiptonDev, с тех самых пор, как *«стал напрямую работать через цп»*

Comment: @VTT C# (как и Java) не интерпретируется и не транслируется на лету. C# компилируется в машинный код, просто в процессе компиляции есть дополнительная стадия - IL, и сама компиляция IL->машинный код происходит уже на целевой машине. При этом есть утилиты для нативной копмиляцией под разные платформы заранее ([.NET Native](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/)). В Java скорее всего такая же картина.

Comment: @PashaPash То, что вы описали, как раз и есть "без использования натив билда он обычно интерпретируется, ну или в лучшем случае транслируется на лету" .

Comment: @VTT "интерпретируется" - это когда код выполняется *построчно*, как в питоне. Со взятием GIL на каждом шаге. Ничего подобного в C#/.NET нет. Интерпретации просто нет, а трансляция C# происходит в момент компиляции. Единственное, что происходит "на лету" - это трансляция IL->машинный код при первом вызове метода, и это вообще никак не описывается фразой "C# - интерпретируется / транслируется на лету". Ну т.е. не интерпретируется вообще, и транслируется не C#, а в остальном - никаких расхождений :)

Comment: @PashaPash Что-то вас куда-то не в ту сторону понесло. Вот питон вполне себе [транслируется на лету в машинный код](http://pypy.org/). А вот [интерактивный интерпретатор для C# выполняющий код построчно](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/repl/).

Comment: @VTT меня никуда не несло, я просто указал на то, что для C# фраза "**обычно** интерпретируется" не соответствует действительности. Она вводит в заблуждение. "Есть возможность" и "обычно" - разные вещи. Для c++ тоже легко нагуглить [построчный интерактивный интерпретатор](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/08/14/cling-cpp-11-interpreter/), но вы же не будете заявлять, что C++ *обычно интерпретируется*. :)

Comment: @PashaPash А вот и нет, в С++ есть радикальное отличие - стандарт четко регламентирует фазы трансляции исходного кода и выполнения программы. Ситуация, когда программа работает, а мы дописываем строчку в исходный код, или даже просто выполняем строчку исходного кода, в нем в принципе не предусмотрена. Так что утилиту по вашей ссылке можно назвать "интерактивным интерпретатором C++" только с большой натяжкой. С другой стороны, его можно без проблем компилировать в байткод для виртуальной машины, причем даже в точно такой же, как и C# (взяв clang и LLILC например).

Comment: Но выполнение этого байткода (даже без генерации нативного машинного кода) ни в какой мере не будет интерпретацией C++ (от которого на этой фазе уже ничего не осталось), в то время как C# будет по-прежнему вполне себе интерпретироваться.

Comment: @VTT так те же аргументы применимы и к c# :) Стандарт языка чётко указывает стадии компиляции (7.1). Ситуация дописывания строчки на ходу в нем тоже не предусмотрена. Утилиту по вашей ссылке можно назвать интерактивный интерпретатором c# только с большой натяжкой - она, очевидно, не поддерживает даже основ языка, вроде вызова того, что объявлено ниже по коду. К сожалению, для полноценного выполнения c# нужна предварительная компиляция всей сборки.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84040/discussion-between-pashapash-and-vtt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это тупиковый путь.

1. Эта экономия на спичках. Вы сэкономите допустим одну миллисекунду и что? При работе с базой данных один запрос будет обрабатываться порядка двести миллисекунд - все ваши нанооптимизации останутся незамеченными: оптимизировать надо там, где наибольший выигрыш от оптимизации, а не там, где вам интересно.
2. Языки "высокоуровневые" как правило абстрагируются от машинных кодов (например, c#/java используют виртуальные машины и байткод) и ваши оптимизации выкинут в мусорку возможность работы на нескольких платформах - или придётся делать оптимизации под каждую платформу.

Answer (score 5):

"Преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех бед" (с) Кнут :)

Первое и главное - оптимизация в разы возможна - но только при замене неэффективного алгоритма более эффективным. Никакие оптимизации в самом коде или при смене языков ускорения в разы не дадут.

Оптимизации на уровне языка возможны, но надо отдавать себе отчет, что в любом случае надо проверять результат и проверять. Ибо даже способы оптимизации меняются - так, в Java раньше давали совет - делать функции побольше, чтоб были поменьше накладные расходы на вызов. С развитием JIT-компиляторов этот совет стал тормозом :)

Добавление низкоуровневости в язык даст минимальный эффект; использовать его можно только в реальных местах - если 99% времени программа крутится в одном цикле - этот цикл можно пытаться ускорить. Для этого надо с профайлером в руках и огнем в очах :) точно выяснить, что именно и где именно тормозит.

Но современный оптимизирующий компилятор вы все равно вряд ли обойдете - скорее всего, сгенерированный им код будет куда быстрее вашего ассемблера. Так ли уж вы хорошо знаете все особенности машинных команд? А оптимизировать ваш ассемблер компилятор, как правило, не будет - что приведет только к тормозам...

P.S. И еще - не забывайте добавлять ко времени работы время разработки. Угрохать лишний день работы, чтобы программа считала на 5 минут быстрее, имеет смысл только если она будет работать тысячи раз. Если программа должна что-то посчитать пару раз, то пусть лучше она будет работать на час дольше, если при этом вы будете ее писать на 2 часа меньше...

P.P.S. `\n` компилятор сам заменит на нужное значение, не трудитесь :) И это ничуть не машинная команда, как вы понимаете...